# javascript - submit button only submit last form in function

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a submit button for 3 different forms. I submit them like this

```
restaurantCreateForm = function(){
    document.getElementById("restaurant-features" ).submit();
    document.getElementById("information_form").submit();
    document.getElementById("restaurant-address").submit();
}
```

However, the function only submits the last form in it. Does anyone know what is the error? I have tried putting them in a for loop and submit one by one but it still submits the last form.

Comment: If you can add your DOM here, that would help debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you submit a form, the browser will send a post request to the server, and will render its response. Therefore the current page will disappear. Thats why you can only send one form, as the page will stop existing afterwards. You could either do background requests with AJAX instead, or you refactor the three forms into one, or into one form after another.

Comment: So is there anyway I can prevent that or I have to use ajax?

Comment: @tri you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas's answer covers your main issue. Further, if your button element is inside of one of your form elements, when clicked it will submit that form by default. You can prevent this by using `event.preventDefault()` in the button's onClick listener, or you can avoid it by placing the button outside of the form element.